# How to find, make link and shorten url text in text block with PHP

Tags: php

So I currently have this...

```
<?php

$textblockwithformatedlinkstoecho = preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-
Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="popup">$1</a>', 
$origtextwithlinks);

echo $textblockwithformatedlinkstoecho;
?>
```

But, I would like to also shorten the clickable link to around 15 chars in length...

Example input text

```
I recommend you visit http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/page3.html?
longtext=ugsdfhsglshghsdghlsg8ysd87t8sdts8dtsdtygs9ysd908yfsd0fyu for more 
information.
```

Required output text

```
I recommend you visit example.com/fol... for more information.
```

Comment: You can use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to manipulate your matches before they are replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to manipulate the matches.

Example:

```
$text = "I recommend you visit http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/page3.html?longtext=ugsdfhsglshghsdghlsg8ys\d87t8sdts8\dtsdtygs9ysd908yfsd0fyu for more information.";

$fixed = preg_replace_callback(
    '!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', 
    function($matches) {
        // Get the fully matched url
        $url  = $matches[0];

        // Do some magic for the link text, like only show the first 15 characters
        $text = strlen($url) > 15
            ? substr($url, 0, 15) . '...'
            : $url;

        // Return the new html link
        return '<a href="' . $url . '" target="popup">' . $text . '</a>';
    }, 
    $text
);

echo $fixed;
```

You probably need to modify your regex though, since it doesn't match the `\`-characters you have in the query string in the url.

Comment: Fantastic thank you, the \ characters in the example link came from me face planting the keyboard so should work fine with real URLs.